# Restriction for Editing Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, list-view, view

I have a document library with 2 public views, currently all users can change the structure of the current view.

I am am looking to achieve the following scenario:

- Users can change to a different view.
- Users cant "edit" the view or in-turn save the view publicly.
- Users should be able to make "personal views" but not public.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the user permissions to **Contribute** instead of 
**Edit**. This will solve your problem.